# Impersonation using an overwriteable method in DBContext of EntityFramework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, impersonation

We have an old WinForms software which we want to migrate to Asp.Net-Core. The old Database requires end user access by an ActiveDirectory user. Our Asp.Net-Core app is running with AppPool-User but the db access needs an impersonated user context.

I only want to execute db calls impersonated.

Which method I have to overwrite in the DBContext-class of EF-Core if I want to hook my custom code before SQL is send to the server?

I'm not interested in hooks which manipulates the internal ChangeTracking.

Comment: What are you interested in? Can you show some code?

Comment: We have an old WinForms software which we want to migrate to Asp.Net-Core. The old Database requires end user access by an ActiveDirectory user. Our Asp.Net-Core app is running whith AppPool-User but the db access needs an impersonated user context (see https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.runimpersonated).
I only want to execute db calls impersonated.

Comment: @Alois why do that at all? What custom code/ What are you trying to do? Add the information *in the question itself*. There are interceptors that can be used but if you want to impersonate, EF is the wrong place to do this.

Comment: @Alois in fact, this question has *nothing* to do with EF Core. You're asking how to impersonate a user in ASP.NET in general. All ASP.NET stacks going back to 2002 offer a way to either impersonate the browser's user, or a specific user. What kind of impersonation are you asking about?

Comment: ASP.NET Core impersonation is [described in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#impersonation) . The docs show how to add impersonation for every request using middleware.

Comment: If you only want to impersonate for data access, you can use an impersonation context around your data access code.

Comment: We tried already to impersonate by middleware. That way will crash because the web-folder is not alowed for end user access (wwwroot). So we get an AccessDenied error if ASP is accessing DLL-Files there when end user context is active. We do not want to allow end users there. Only the database requires end user access so we impersonate each request by hand at the moment. But that is a bunch of boiler plate code. The interceptors sounds interesting but I don't know how to pack them into a delegate for the Impersonate method.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using **EF Core 3.0+** you can use [Interceptors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors). Keep in mind that database interceptors are supported for relational database providers only, though. They provide you access to the typical db command operations, including connection and transaction management.

You can [TAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tags) your queries as to easily recognize them in the interceptor logic. You will find good examples for that in the *Interceptors* page.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, maybee the interceptors are my way to go. I tried to use them but I'm failed because the impersonate-method expects a delegate a parameter. It seems that the interceptor code cannot be delegated.

Answer (score 0):

Would the override of Save itself do the trick for you?

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
  public override int SaveChanges()
    {
      RunInpersonated();
      return base.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Edit: Now that I think of it again, that's only for write access, not for read, and you probably need both.

You could also implement repository pattern, and add your impersonation logic there. Also SQL for read queries is actually sent to the DB when you execute methods like `ToListAsync()` on `IQueryable` and fetching the results. You could write your own extension methods like `ToList`, add your impersonation thing there, and than call normal `ToList` method.

Comment: The OP's question isn't about EF Core at all, it's about ASP.NET Core impersonation

Comment: You are right, actually. Just giving ideas on what one could override, as asked.

Comment: We are using Repository-Pattern and we impersonate each method already. But that is a bunch of boiler plate code. As you already said, override the save method is only one side of the coin. The queries are the other. Impersonate the whole request in ASP does not work because the whole web server is crashing then because a common user is not allowed to access System-dll's. I only want to impersonate requests to the database.